# Remove the old design title of an anchor tag after applying CSS on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am able to change design of the `title` attribute inside anchor tag, even though the default one is coming along with changed one.

I'm wondering if it's possible to remove default `title` tooltip as shown below?

[image: Title tooltip]

---

Here's my code so far:

```
<a title="Edit"><img alt="" src="dist/img/edit.png" ></a>

a:hover {
    color: red;
    position: relative;
}

a[title]:hover:after {
    content: attr(title);
    padding: 2px 4px;
    color: #333;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    z-index: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom,
                      color-stop(0, #eeeeee), color-stop(1, #cccccc));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: CSS can't change attributes of DOM elements. You must use js for this.

Comment: Not possible with css..

Comment: Then how it could be possible and what js i have to use?

Comment: use jquery to make it easier

Comment: what all styles you need to remove from old one. Try using $('#link_id).css('color', '#900');$('#link_id).css('padding', '0px'); etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a simple way to do what you want, while still using the `title` attribute. So the answer to your original question:

> Is it possible to remove default title tooltip?

**Answer:** Probably not possible. Each browser decides how to handle the `title` attribute. So unless there is some hacky way of disabling the default behavior *for each browser*, there is probably no way of achieving this.

*Edit:* Apparently this [isn't possible in Chrome](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/ygoNhTB5K1Y), but is [possible in Firefox](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=1562905).

---

#### Alternative solution

Unless you *absolutely must* use the `title` attribute specifically, the easiest and simplest solution would probably be to just use another tag instead of `title`, for example `data-title`. That way, you're not triggering the default behavior while still achieving your default styles.

```css
a:hover {
    color: red;
    position: relative;
}

a[data-title]:hover:after {
    content: attr(data-title);
    padding: 2px 4px;
    color: #333;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    z-index: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom,
                      color-stop(0, #eeeeee), color-stop(1, #cccccc));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
}
```

```html
<a data-title="Edit"><img alt="" src="dist/img/edit.png" ></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript [Element.removeAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute)

```js
  //select all anchor with a given title, in this case a[title=Edit]
var anchor = document.querySelectorAll("a[title=Edit]");

for(var i=0; i<anchor.length;i++){
  //anchor[i].title = "";
  anchor[i].removeAttribute("title");
}
```

```css
a:hover {
    color: red;
    position: relative;
}

a[title]:hover:after {
    content: attr(title);
    padding: 2px 4px;
    color: #333;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    z-index: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom,
                      color-stop(0, #eeeeee), color-stop(1, #cccccc));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
}
```

```html
<a title="Edit"><img alt="" src="dist/img/edit.png" ></a>
<a title="Save"><img alt="" src="dist/img/edit.png" ></a>
<a title="remove"><img alt="" src="dist/img/edit.png" ></a>
```

Comment: I'm still getting both the default and the custom `title` tags showing.